# Trying To Get A Full Contact Report

Tags: contacts, duplicate-contacts

There’s been a lot of turnover at my job, which means there are tons of duplicate entries in our civi records. I’m trying to do a reconciliation to remove the duplicates by downloading all the contacts and going through the excel by hand, then merging them in civi, but I can only get a report for each GROUP (we have hundreds of groups and they overlap, so that’s not useful.)

Is there a way for me to just get a FULL contact report of every single person/entry in the system? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can get all contacts by simply going to Advanced Search and clicking search without entering any criteria at all.

But if you're looking to remove duplicates, it might be less painful to set up appropriate dedupe rules and then use each rule in Find and Merge Duplicate Contacts. Depending what your data looks like, you can do things like first and last Name, just email, last name and email, last name and phone, first name and email, even last name and first four letters of first name, etc.

Comment: Documentation is at https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/common-workflows/deduping-and-merging/